Canonical Tag is faulty respectively inequal in Shopware6
I will post 3 screenshots, which will illustrate my problem

How to achieve in Shopware6 having equal entries for both, URL and Canonical via Backend, database manipulation or each other possibilities?
For further informations:Following Query(Screenshot II) shows up following response(Screenshot III).


